# Append php array to php file using Linux command line

Tags: php, linux, bash, sed

I have a php file and I need to append an array to it using Linux's CLI. I'm assuming sed is the tool for this, but I don't know how to do so as I'm very unfamiliar with Linux and php.

Example config.php

```
$CONFIG = array (
  'installed' => true,
  'instanceid' => 'sdsdfsfdsdf',
  'ldapProviderFactory' => 'OCA\\User_LDAP\\LDAPProviderFactory',
);
```

Array that needs added

```
array (
    'class' => '\\OC\\Files\\ObjectStore\\S3',
    'arguments' =>
    array (
      'val1' => 'val1x',
      'val2' => 'val1x',
    ),
  ),
```

I also thought I could use `cat` to append it, but it'd cause a syntax error since the file needs to end in `);`

The final file would appear as such

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'installed' => true,
  'instanceid' => 'sdsdfsfdsdf',
  'ldapProviderFactory' => 'OCA\\User_LDAP\\LDAPProviderFactory',
  array (
    'class' => '\\OC\\Files\\ObjectStore\\S3',
    'arguments' =>
    array (
      'val1' => 'val1x',
      'val2' => 'val1x',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Show the exact result you want.  `cat` can do the job, and you can edit the result after.

Comment: @Nic3500 I've added an example

Answer (score 1):

Great, with the sample output you want, here is a solution, using `awk`.
I put the original text, and what you want to add into text files.

## orig.txt

```
$CONFIG = array (
  'installed' => true,
  'instanceid' => 'sdsdfsfdsdf',
  'ldapProviderFactory' => 'OCA\\User_LDAP\\LDAPProviderFactory',
  );
```

## add.txt

```
  array (
    'class' => '\\OC\\Files\\ObjectStore\\S3',
    'arguments' =>
    array (
    'val1' => 'val1x',
    'val2' => 'val1x',
    ),
  ),
```

And the `awk` script is merge.awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

!/);/ {
    print
}
END {
    system("cat add.txt")
    print ");"
}
```

- call it like that: `./merge.awk orig.txt`
- it will show the output in stdout (i.e. your terminal).
- `awk` processes lines in `orig.txt` one by one
- every line that does not contain `);` is printed
- the `END` block, prints the content of `add.txt`, and prints back the `);` to close off the PHP array.

## The output is

```
$ ./merge.awk orig.txt
$CONFIG = array (
  'installed' => true,
  'instanceid' => 'sdsdfsfdsdf',
  'ldapProviderFactory' => 'OCA\\User_LDAP\\LDAPProviderFactory',
  array (
    'class' => '\\OC\\Files\\ObjectStore\\S3',
    'arguments' =>
    array (
    'val1' => 'val1x',
    'val2' => 'val1x',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the script after saving it, and I'm getting a `merge.awk: 3: Syntax error: ")" unexpected` error. I opened vim and pasted what you gave me, any idea why?

Comment: hum, I just tried to recreate the merge.awk file using vi (i.e. vim) and it worked ok for me.  Are you on linux or some linux subsystem for windows?  For your `awk`, I used GNU awk 4.1.4, make sure you use GNU awk as well.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. If I try to run `sudo ./merge.awk file.txt`, I'm getting `sudo: ./merge.awk: command not found` even though I'm in the directory that `merge.awk` exists.

Comment: Why sudo?  The PHP files are owned by root?  That would be unusual... Ensure that once you created merge.awk, do `chmod 700 merge.awk` for your user to be able to execute the file.  And your user must be able to read and write the txt files